# Page loading times of Google's static vs dynamic maps for mobile users?

Tags: performance, google-maps, mobile

For mobile users, will their be a significant difference in page loading times for Google's interactive maps vs their static ones?

Thanks

Comment: This is comparing apples to oranges as the two APIs are very different. Please define "performance". The obvious answer is "one moves, the other doesn't" which is (also obviously) not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This map http://www.acleach.me.uk/gmaps/v3/map-customlabels.htm is 243.6kb (depends on screen size and number of map tiles).

A broadly equivalent static map http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x640&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&format=png&center=-34.397,150.644&zoom=8 is a single image at 80.6kb.

So: there is a difference, and a 200% increase could be said to be significant. However, Version 3 is intended to be lightweight and it may be that 250kb is acceptable. That will depend on whether the interactivity of dynamic maps is required: if it's required, then loading 250kb may be a reasonable "penalty". If there's no requirement for a dynamic map, then a static map will almost certainly be smaller and load faster.

Comment: When you say it depends on screensize, were you testing on a mobile sized screen? Thanks

Comment: I was testing on a screen of a similar size to my iPad. I've just done it again with a smaller screen and got a larger number (go figure!): 384kb, a 350% increase on a static map. But I don't think that changes the conclusion of my answer. 200% or 350% may be a significant difference, but less than 400kb may be acceptable if you want a dynamic map. If you don't need a dynamic map, a static map will be smaller and load faster.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is: Yes, There will be a difference is page loading times.  The static image is just that, a static image.  The dynamic is composed of "tiles".  Each tile has a certain data size.  The dynamic page pre-loads a certain amount of tiles.  For example: Static image is 50kb.  Dynamic image display is 50 kb, but it pre-loads 4 tiles around it at 50kb each.  You know 250kb of traffic for the image, plus the 5 HTTP gets requests, not to mention you also have the javascript overhead of the dynamic map library.

To go further, pure data size isn't the only consideration.  As I said earlier, you have multiple GET requests to fetch those tiles.  On a mobile network (3g) etc, your network latency is typically higher due to more hops to reach a core network.  Most mobile browser only allow 2 - 4 get requests at a time.  Therefore, you have to wait for the max amount of requests to drop below the threshold before the browser can initiate another GET request.

I hope this helps.
Mike